# BLE connection while ranging beacons

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about BLE, and it's quite simple. There is a native app for iOS and Android, and we want them both to have the same functionalities:

1. Scan / range for beacons
2. Connect with a BLE device

Both is quite simple, but I want to make sure it's possible to do **simultaneously**. So, also after having setup the connection with the BLE device, keep on scanning for beacons. Both functionalities shouldn't influence each other.

I know it's possible to connect with multiple devices, but I could not find anything about ranging beacons while connected.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: On iOS Beacons and peripherals are handled by different libraries; core location and core Bluetooth. You can range beacons with core location while connected to a peripheral with core Bluetooth.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I expect for Android the same behavior. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made a proof of concept for both Android and iOS. It works fine, no problems. When connected to a BLE device it's still posible to range beacons.

Comment: For Android 7 it can be problematic when you start and stop scanning for BLE devices or beacons more than five times within 30 seconds, as described in a blog here:
https://blog.classycode.com/undocumented-android-7-ble-behavior-changes-d1a9bd87d983